# Enable Streams on QLDB?

Tags: database, amazon-kinesis, amazon-qldb

for an existing table on dynamo, we can enable streams. Is there a similar functionality to QLDB? 
I remember seeing in posts that Kinesis Data Streams integration with QLDB was in preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLDB Streams is now available as a feature that allows changes made to the journal to be continuously written in near real time to a destination Kinesis Data Stream. QLDB stream writes the data to Kinesis Data Streams in three types of records: control, block summary, and revision details. Please find further details in the following [developer guide](https://qldbguide.com/docs/introduction/qldb-streams/).

Comment: Wow! That's pretty exciting

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** [Streams are now GA](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-qldb-supports-real-time-streaming/).

[Streams are in preview](https://twitter.com/marcbowes/status/1202758663468765189). You can signup by contacting qldb-outbound AT amazon.com.